# pandas dataframe subplot on multiple dataframe and columns showing same columns on same graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below code shows two dataframe's columns separately like below image.

How can I show the same columns on same graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# create dummy pandas dataframes
pd1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(22),'b':np.random.random(22),
                    'c':np.random.random(22)})
pd2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.random(22),'b':np.random.random(22),
                    'c':np.random.random(22)})
#create subplot figure with having two side by side plots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3,ncols=2,figsize=(12,6))
# plot first pandas frame in subplot style
pd1.plot(ax = axes[:,0],subplots=True) 
# plot second pandas frame in subplot style
pd2.plot(ax = axes[:,1],subplots=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=3,figsize=(12,6))

for c, ax in zip(pd1, axes):
    pd1[c].plot(ax=ax, label=f'{c} pd1')
    pd2[c].plot(ax=ax, label=f'{c} pd2')

    ax.legend()
```

Output:

[image]